# C++ Avoid Temporary Object Destruction using Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, rvalue-reference, temporary-objects

I have a `std::vector` of *Tree*s, a custom type, and I have a loop which pushes back a tot of *Tree*s to the vector. The problem is: I need push back ***temporary*** *Tree* objects, but, at the same time, I have to avoid them getting deallocated (I thought adding a *rvalue reference constructor* to the *Tree* class would have solved the problem, but it didn't).

Tree class:

```
class Tree
{
    public:
        Tree();
        Tree(Coords, Pixel, Pixel, uint8_t);
        Tree(const Tree&);
        Tree(const Tree&&);
        ~Tree();

        Tree& operator=(const Tree&);
        Tree& operator=(const Tree&&);

        void draw();
        void chop(uint8_t);

        Coords getCoords() const {return log->coords;}

        const Log& getLog() const
        { 
            return *log;
        }

        const Crown& getCrown() const
        {
            return *crown;
        }

    private:
        Log*     log;
        Crown* crown;
};

Tree::Tree():
    log(nullptr), crown(nullptr)
{

}

Tree::Tree(Coords c, Pixel wd, Pixel lvs, uint8_t h):
    log(new Log(c, wd, h)), crown(new Crown({c.x, static_cast<coordsCounter>(c.y + h)}, lvs, getRandBetweenEqu(3, 4)))
{
    draw();
}

Tree::Tree(const Tree& tree):
    log(new Log(tree.log->coords, tree.log->texture, tree.log->height)),
    crown(new Crown(tree.crown->coords, tree.crown->texture, tree.crown->width))
{
    draw();
}

Tree::Tree(const Tree&& tree):
    log(new Log(tree.log->coords, tree.log->texture, tree.log->height)),
    crown(new Crown(tree.crown->coords, tree.crown->texture, tree.crown->width))
{
    draw();
}

Tree& Tree::operator=(const Tree& tree)
{
    if(log != nullptr) delete log;
    if(crown != nullptr) delete crown;

    log   = new Log(*tree.log);
    crown = new Crown(*tree.crown);

    return *this;
}

Tree& Tree::operator=(const Tree&& tree)
{
    if(log != nullptr) delete log;
    if(crown != nullptr) delete crown;

    log   = new Log(*tree.log);
    crown = new Crown(*tree.crown);

    return *this;
}

void Tree::draw()
{
    log->draw();
    crown->draw();
}

Tree::~Tree()
{
    chop(0);
}

void Tree::chop(uint8_t h)
{
    if(crown != nullptr)
    {
        delete crown;
        crown = nullptr;
    }

    if(h == 0)
    {
        if(log != nullptr)
        {
            delete log;
            log = nullptr;
        }
    } else
    {
        if(h <= log->height)
        {
            log->chop(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Function pushing back trees:

```
void growTrees(uint8_t m, uint8_t M)
{
    Coords treeCoords;

    for(coordsCounter i = 5; i < grid.getMaxXY().x - 4; i += getRandBetweenEqu(m, M))
    {
        if((treeCoords = getFirstBlock({i, static_cast<coordsCounter>(grid.getMaxXY().y - 1)}, 's', grassTexture) + Coords{0, 1}) != Coords{0, 1})
        {
            trees.push_back(Tree(treeCoords, woodTexture, leavesTexture, getRandBetweenEqu(minTreeHeight, maxTreeHeight)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you construct them, you need to deconstruct them, even if moved...

Comment: Which is the real problem? Do your class follows [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: *but, at the same time, I have to avoid them getting deallocated* -- Sounds like your `Trees` class is lacking proper copy semantics.

Comment: I have defined all the custom special methods

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the code you are using.

Comment: Which part of the code, exactly?

Comment: Enough of the code to make an [mre].

Comment: Responses may be better if you can include code for the `Trees` class. In modern C++ you can often get the best results by not defining constructors ilor assignment operators.  You might also emplace rather than pushing onto the vector.

Comment: why do you need to avoid the temporary objects getting deallocated?

Comment: Because when `Tree`s get deallocated they also get cancelled from the `grid`, which is kinda like the level of the game (they disappear from the screen, basically)

Comment: @DarkoNaito_09 *Because when Trees get deallocated they also get cancelled from the grid, which is kinda like the level of the game* -- IMO, that's too much "business logic" to be placed in a copy constructor.  A copy constructor's job should be simple -- make a copy, without all of the side-effects going on.  Maybe you should consider making the class non-copyable.

Comment: I get it, but I really dislike the idea of having draw() and chop() functions separated from the constructor and distructor. Also, making the class non-copyable wouldn't solve the problem I'm having at the moment.

Comment: @DarkoNaito_09 -- If it is decided that an object is copyable, it must make logical sense as to what it means to make a copy.  For example, stream classes in C++ are not copyable.  What would it mean to make a copy of, say, a file stream?  Two files being written or read from?   That's why streams are not copyable, because it doesn't make sense.   However, the stream classes are *movable*, and maybe you should just drop the copying and make the class just moveable.

Comment: Also, note that copying is something the *compiler* can do, without you actually doing anything explicit.  So now you will have copies going off all over the running of the program, and you have little to no control over it.  That's why copying must be simple, efficient, and with no (visible) side effects.

Comment: I =deleted all the constructors/functions which involved copying, and now I'm getting `stl_algobase.h:400:18: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr Tree& Tree::operator=(const Tree&)'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231046/discussion-between-darkonaito-09-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 0):

Your move constructor/assignment operator are actually copying the objects, they should take non-const rvalue references and set the moved from object to some empty value.

```
Tree::Tree(Tree&& tree):
    log(std::exchange(tree.log, nullptr)),
    crown(std::exchange(tree.crown, nullptr))
{
    draw();
}
Tree& Tree::operator=(Tree&& tree)
{
    std::swap(tree.log, log);
    std::swap(tree.crown, crown);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: In fact, you can combine the copy-assignment and move-assignment operators together into a single implementation: `Tree& Tree::operator=(Tree tree) { std::swap(tree.log, log); std::swap(tree.crown, crown); return *this; }` This allows the caller to decide whether to copy-construct or move-construct the `tree` parameter as needed.